# IOS 8 ignoring my Media Queries

Tags: ios, css, responsive-design, html-email

I've built a responsive email however, on IOS8 (in Apple mail client and in phones browser) the media queries are being ignored. Note: this is across all the IOS 8 iPhones

I've not provided a JSFIDDLE as it doesn't really work for emails since the code is all in one place.

Email can be found here

http://news.yfish.co.uk/e/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/preview/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Rugby World Cup 2015</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />

        <style type="text/css">

            #outlook a { padding: 0; }
            .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; } .ExternalClass { width:100%; }                
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
            body, table, td, a { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
            table, td { mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; }
            img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
            body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            img { border: 0; height: auto; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; }
            table { border-collapse: collapse!important; }
            body { height: 100%!important; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%!important; background-color: #e6e6e7; }
            a:visited { color: #ffffff; }

            @media screen {
                @font-face {
                    font-family: 'humanst';
                    src: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.eot);
                    src: url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
                         url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.woff2) format('woff2'),
                         url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
                         url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.ttf) format('truetype'),
                         url(http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/HUM521N-webfont.svg#humanst521_btroman) format('svg');
                    font-weight: normal;
                    font-style: normal;
                }

            }

                 #fade {
                    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards;
                    -moz-animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards;
                    -o-animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards;
                    animation: fadeIn 1.5s forwards;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
                    0% {opacity: 0; }
                    70% {opacity: 0; }
                    100% {opacity: 1; }
                }

                @-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
                    0% {opacity: 0; }
                    70% {opacity: 0; }
                    100% {opacity: 1; }
                }

                @-o-keyframes fadeIn {
                    0% {opacity: 0; }
                    70% {opacity: 0; }
                    100% {opacity: 1; }
                }

                @keyframes fadeIn {
                    0% {opacity: 0; }
                    70% {opacity: 0; }
                    100% {opacity: 1; }
                }


                #fadeUp {
                    -webkit-animation: imagefadeInUp 2s 0.8s forwards;
                    -moz-animation: imagefadeInUp 2s 0.8s forwards;
                    -o-animation: imagefadeInUp 2s 0.8s forwards;
                    animation: imagefadeInUp 2s 0.8s forwards;
                    visibility: hidden!important;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
                    0% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px);}
                    50% {opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); visibility: visible; }
                    100% {opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0); visibility: visible;}
                }

                @-moz-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
                    0% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px);}
                    50% {opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(50px); visibility: visible;}
                    100% {opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0); visibility: visible;}
                }

                @-o-keyframes imagefadeInUp {
                    0% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(50px);}
                    50% {opacity: 0; -o-transform: translateY(50px); visibility: visible;}
                    100% {opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateX(0); visibility: visible;}
                }

                @keyframes imagefadeInUp {
                    0% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(50px);}
                    50% {opacity: 0; transform: translateY(50px); visibility: visible;}
                    100% {opacity: 1; transform: translateX(0); visibility: visible;}
                }               

            @media screen and (max-width: 600px), and screen (max-device-width: 600px) {

                body { width: auto!important; }
                table[class="fullWidth"] { width: 100%!important; }
                table[class="contentWidth"] { width: 90%!important; }
                td[class="center"] { text-align: center!important; }
                table[class="centerTable"] { display: block!important; float: none!important; margin: 0 auto!important; }
                td[class="fullCell"] { display: block!important; float: none!important; width: 100%!important;  }
                td[id="padding"] { padding-bottom: 20px!important; }

            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 520px), and screen (max-device-width: 520px) {

                table[class="mainTitle"] { width: 95%!important; }
                img[class="imgScale"] { width: 100%!important; height: auto!important; }

            }

             @media screen and (max-width: 480px), and screen (max-device-width: 480px) {

                td[class="mobileCell"] { display: block!important; float: left!important; width: 100%!important; padding: 0!important; }
                td[class="mobileHide"] { display: none!important; }
                table[class="logoCenter"] { display: block!important; float: none!important; margin: 0 auto!important; margin-bottom: 20px!important;  }
                table[class="gifScale"] { width: 95%!important; }

             }

             @media screen and (max-width: 370px), and screen (max-device-width: 370px) {

                 table[class="mobileTitle"] { width: 90%!important; }

             }

        </style>

</head>
<body bottommargin="0" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0" bgcolor="#e6e6e7">

    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#e6e6e7" style="background-color: #e6e6e7;"><!-- wrapper -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#e6e6e7">

                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#595959">

                            <table width="99%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" bgcolor="#595959"><!-- header -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="33%" style="padding-left: 20px;" class="mobileCell">

                                        <table width="105" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="logoCenter">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/www.yfish.co.uk/"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/logo.png" width="105" height="36" alt="THINK OUTSIDE THE TANK" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="img-scale"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" align="center" class="mobileCell">

                                        <table width="91" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center"><!-- social -->
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/www.facebook.com/YellowFishBrighton" target="_blank" class="facebook"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/facebook.png" width="13" height="21" alt="Like us on Facebook" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="20">&nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/twitter.com/yfishchat" target="_blank" class="twitter"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/twitter.png" width="22" height="15" alt="Follow us Twitter" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="20">&nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="mailto:contact@yfish.co.uk" class="mail"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/mail.png" width="16" height="11" alt="Contact us!" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table><!-- end social -->

                                    </td>
                                    <td width="33%" style="font-family: 'humanst', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 15px; text-align: right; vertical-align: middle; padding-right: 20px;" valign="middle" class="mobileHide">
                                        <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/e/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/0/preview/" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">It's a crime, not to view online</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="block">
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- end header -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#ffc216">

                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffc216">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="50">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">

                                        <table width="680" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="contentWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">

                                                    <table width="505" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="mainTitle">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/title.png" width="505" height="61" alt="Rugby World Cup" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="imgScale" id="fade">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">

                                                    <table width="437" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="gifScale">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/flag.gif" width="437" height="233" alt="Rugby" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="imgScale" id="fadeUp">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="30">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                        

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="25">&nbsp;

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <table width="680" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="fullWidth">
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="50" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">

                                        <table width="356" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="mobileTitle">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                <img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/titletwo.png" width="356" height="52" alt="Join us on the 19th September" style="display: block; border: 0;" class="imgScale">
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: georgia, verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; line-height: 22px; color: #424242; text-align: center; font-style: italic;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                                    Your V.I.P invitation
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">

                                        <table width="520" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="contentWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-family: 'humanst', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; color: #424242; text-align: left;" class="center">

        Previewer I’d love if you could join me at our Yellow Fish table for an afternoon and night of hospitality, Yellow Fish style!<br><br> 

        Aside of full hospitality and category A seats at the fabulous AMEX stadium, I’d like to invite you to stay overnight in Brighton, provide you with transfers to/from the match, enjoy a bit of Brighton nightlife and then brunch on Sunday before you head off. All you have to do is get to Brighton!<br><br>

        Kick off is at 16:45 so I’d plan for being in to Brighton around lunch time and once I have more information I’ll firm up details.
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">

                                        <table width="520" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="contentWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="50%" valign="top" class="fullCell" id="padding">

                                                    <table width="248" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="centerTable">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/www.yfish.co.uk/thank-you/"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/attending.png" width="248" height="45" alt="I can attend" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>

                                                </td>
                                                <td width="50%" valign="top" class="fullCell">

                                                    <table width="248" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="right" class="centerTable">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/www.yfish.co.uk/a-real-shame/"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/unable.png" width="248" height="45" alt="I'm unable to attend" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff">

                                        <table width="520" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="contentWidth">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="font-family: 'humanst', arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; color: #424242; text-align: left;" class="center">
                                                It should be great fun, a great game watching the Bokkers in Brighton and I really hope you can join me.<br><br>

                                                Best
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>&nbsp;

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>

                                                    <table width="112" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" class="centerTable">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                            <img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/maria.png" width="112" height="33" alt="Maria" style="display: block; border: 0;">
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="100" bgcolor="#ffffff">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="25">&nbsp;

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#595959">

                            <table width="680" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#595959" class="fullWidth"><!-- footer -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center">

                                        <table width="105" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <a href="http://news.yfish.co.uk/op/9F640D904C5C4FC1AAD220AFAE5C37B3/4/www.yfish.co.uk/"><img src="http://news.yfish.co.uk/repository/news.yfish.co.uk/34/14553/logo.png" width="105" height="36" alt="THINK OUTSIDE THE TANK" border="0" style="display: block; border: 0;"></a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; line-height: 15px; color: #ffffff; text-align: center;">
                                    Tel +44 (0) 1273 223 500 | Fax +44 (0) 1273 323 257 | <a href="mailto:contact@yfish.co.uk" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">contact@yfish.co.uk</a><br><br>

Copyright &copy; 2014 Yellow Fish
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td height="25">&nbsp;

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- end footer -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><!-- end wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

I've tried removing all other queries and also tried altering Query widths. No luck!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you test it in an email blast or just by the local file?

Comment: Tested via Email On Acid and via devices

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, nobody has been able to provide me with a solution.

Fortunately, I have figrued it out. IOS 8 DOES NOT like commas in media queries.

When removing the comma:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px), and screen (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and screen (max-device-width: 480px) {}
```

This fixes everything. However, the comma did not cause issues on IOS 7

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the comma has stopped the queries working in desktop Chrome. I know they're for mobile but the perfectionist within me is screaming! :(